# Message informing me of previous post flag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags

I flagged a post for mod attention.

A few days later I went back and tried to flag again (as if there is one I missed an indication I'd previously flagged).

I was only told that I'd previously flagged a post once I tried to submit the flag.

Could we have an indication that the post has been flagged already?

I'm not sure if you could re-flag, so I'm proposing one of 2 things:

If you can re-flag, then could there be some way of indicating on the post that you've already flagged it, maybe changing the flag link to say 're-flag', then when opening it, the reason you previously flagged being greyed out.

If you can't re-flag, then should the flag link just be disabled/hidden.

Comment: I think rarely happens to flag a post you've already flagged, and it's not big deal... it will save you 1 click per month?

Comment: It's definitely not a big deal, just thought i'd request it to add it to the pile (near the bottom).

Comment: Hmm, it seems that you already found the notification that you've flagged the post previously. You can re-flag for a different reason than you flagged for previously, so disabling/hiding the link altogether isn't a good option.

Comment: Maybe it should be changed to say 're-flag'? Or maybe on the box to choose flag reason it should have a symbol indicating the reason you previously gave.

Comment: Reflagging doesn't work, at least in the case where the "other" option is used.  See: [If I can't flag a post, don't wait until after I've typed an explanation to tell me so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184809/if-i-cant-flag-a-post-dont-wait-until-after-ive-typed-an-explanation-to-tell)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) The flag dialog now indicates if you have a pending flag ("this is the flag that you have raised") and greys out flag options you can no longer use due to previous flag retraction.