# Tell me I've already flagged before allowing me to click Flag Answer again

Tags: feature-request, flags

Just for the heck of it I clicked the flag link on a post i'd previous flagged again.

[image]

I was surprised to see that although my overall choice ("it needs moderator attention") had been selected I could still select again and click flag answer. Doing this gives me the error/information message below:

[image]

I guess the flagging dialog still pops up in case I want to change my flag reason, but maybe it should select the flag reason entirely ("not an answer" in the below case) with the "Flag Answer" button greyed out unless the selection is changed.

Comment: Very similar feature request on Meta Programmers: [Indicator to tell me I already flagged a question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5784/indicator-to-tell-me-i-already-flagged-a-question)

Comment: I rejected that flag, by the way. (Just kidding!!)

Comment: Didn't see that thanks. Should it be migrated here, and this made a duplicate of it?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Yeah, I wasn't 100% sure whether flagging was appropriate for that post; it's a bit borderline. (Oh, wait, april 1st was a few days ago!).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett No, not really. It's not exactly the same question, just quite similar.

Comment: dup? [Message informing me of previous post flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103853/997587)