# Can we get the new imgur uploader for chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, user-interface, uploader, imgur

I actually like the new imgur uploader (besides the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317578/358161) issue)

[image]

But the one in chat is very dated. It'd be nice if we could get the same one for chat. Mostly for the drag and drop feature, but also for UI.

[image]