# How is the new image uploader supposed to look?

Tags: support, design, images, uploader

**This is how everyone else's screenshots look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576/366373):**

> [image]

**This is how it looks for me:**

> [image]
>
> [image]

I have tested it on the latest Firefox on Windows 10, the latest Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04, and on an extremely old version of Firefox (52.02). The result is the same for all of them.

It also does not look right; the coloured links and normal text don't fit in with the rest. The look in the other user's shots looks more like an intended design.

#### Is this how it is for everyone?

Comment: Yes it does look so for me too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/StiVz.png (double image, the uploaded one is how it looks without image selected)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should look the same for everyone - and it should look the way you see it.

[The original rollout of the inline uploader](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/editor-improvements-for-images-and-links) looked as it is shown in your first screenshot; this ended up being problematic for scenarios where someone wanted to upload an image from a URL however.

So the UI was tweaked a bit to include better instructions and explicit links for browsing local images and pasting URLs: 
[No option to upload image from URL anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317578/no-option-to-upload-image-from-url-anymore/317591#317591)