# Can't submit Custom -> Other flag after previous flag

Tags: bug, flags, flag-dialog

I got a clear-cut `Not An Answer` in the review queue and flagged it as such. However, just before moving on, I noticed something else that I figured required Moderator attention.

So I clicked my way through the dialog - and I could see that I would have been blocked from flagging it as `NAA` again, which is obviously correct.

Filled in my reason for the moderators, clicked `Flag Answer` and *then* I got the "You have already flagged this for moderator attention" - and I can see that the (latest, detailed) flag has not been registered.

Shouldn't the dialog prevent me from entering the reason, if the flag can't be handled to begin with?

EDIT: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184809/213634) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175074/213634) are similar questions I just noticed. I don't know if they are exact dupes, but in particularly [Monicas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184809/213634) question seem to be *very* close to mine although Monicas question is a feature request, while this is marked as a bug.

Comment: I got something like that too yesterday.

Comment: At times I would like to cast both a regular spam flag _and_ an extra "please newk this user" other flag.

Comment: @JanDvorak I think an approved spam flag automatically penalizes the posting user.

Comment: @AndersUP sure, that's not really enough. I've seen around six posts having been posted by a new account before it went silent. Question ban? I can only guess.

Comment: @JanDvorak Check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/213634) - specifically: The spam flag is designed to eliminate posts with no relevant content and to penalize the authors.

Comment: @JanDvorak With spam flags I hardly, if ever, follow up. It is more the case where I click on the user after flagging a post and then notice something more. Usually, they have other posts that can then be flagged with the `Other`-reason, but in this case, the user had only made one post total.

Comment: Can you give us an example question so we can replicate?

Comment: @skliwz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925789/how-can-i-add-a-class-attribute-to-html-beginform-in-mvc3-4-preserving-the-min/19268395#19268395 is the exact link that caused this. This was `NAA` and was the answer I then tried to flag again, specifically since the user in question at the time had no other answers.

Comment: @Sklivvz Does that help, or do you need more?

Comment: I only see a NAA flag from you and no review. What am I missing?

Comment: @Sklivvz No review as in you can see I got it for review and then skipped it?

Comment: I don't think we can support windows in one tab updating on state changes in another window. It's possible, but probably not worth it.

Comment: @Sklivvz It wasn't the case that the windows were open at the same time. the flow was that I submitted the NAA flag and only then saw the other thing I figured should be flagged. And as I said, I'm 90% certain that the NAA was grayed out when I flagged the second time.

Comment: @Sklivvz I just saw [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184809/213634) today - I'm guessing they are at least related or my question might even be a duplicate of that.