# Make it easier for moderators to see flag responses

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

Moderators can see all the flag-handling for a site.  What we get is the post link, the flag, and whether it was accepted or declined.  For example:

[image: flag processed]

(I've clipped out the identifying information here.)

On my site, when we decline a custom flag we generally write a response.  Sometimes we even do that for helpful flags!  But that response doesn't show up in this view.  For example, I wrote a custom response to this one:

[image: custom flag]

The text of the flag is what the flagger typed.  After handling the flag I wanted to get back to my response (for a mod discussion), and I had to click through to the post, then the user, then the flags page, and then find the flag to see the response.  Somebody else reviewing my actions wouldn't even know that there *was* a response without doing all that.

Further, the flag response does not show up if there are subsequent flags, though the earlier flag does:

[image: flags on a post]

Could we please have flag responses show up in both places, like they do for a user's flag history?  It would make moderation easier if we could see both sides of the "conversation" rather than just the one side.

This request isn't about [users seeing their own past flags when flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212784/162102).  This request is for moderators.