# My memory is terrible. Please tell me what I wrote in mod-call flags!

Tags: feature-request, flags

When flagging for moderator attention, I try to give concise and useful detail, then send.

Sometimes there are many issues and I point out each by shorthand, sometimes I just focus on the highly egregious one and hope the moderator will check thoroughly.

I'll also come back to a question or answer and want to flag it, to see that I already did! Occasionally my flag hasn't resolved yet. That's okay - mods are busy people and a few hours isn't much. Less frequently, I encounter a string of content from (a) user(s) that needs an encompassing behind-the-scenes check. I've already flagged one or two for whatever reason, but now I want to add the request for a wider check.

But all I know is that I flagged for mod attention. I don't know what I wrote, or what exactly it was about, and I don't want to cover something twice (for the obvious reason, and as to avoid the impression that I'm copy-pasting a flag, because that's annoying to them and doesn't get the flag done faster).

**Can we please have the mod-flag comment saved in the comment section, if the flag has not yet been resolved?**

Comment: 1. I had a look but nothing comes up when searching for mod flags, so if this has already been processed, please point out the earlier discussion. 2. Yes, I can go to my profile and check the pending flags, but this requires opening two consecutive new pages, and touchscreen already makes the flag dialogue hard enough.

Comment: Regarding 2: This is sufficiently rare that I consider cluttering the interface with this information is the lesser evil compared to you having to open a few pages.

Comment: No duplicate. The other Q&A explains reading the summary *when a user has already got to it*. This question raises the point that getting to the summary is (significant) additional workload, while the dialogue related to the flag under discussion is already open and present. @gnat

Comment: The comment space already exists regardless, and the dialogue is only open because the user wants to add a flag, to which knowing about the existing flag and (in the case of mod-flags) the note attached to it, is extremely pertinent information. @Wrzlprmft

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212784/when-flagging-could-we-see-any-previous-flags-weve-raised-on-the-same-post

Comment: Neither of the questions mentioned resolve this one. One deals with reading the flag summary, which is the entire problem to be avoided. The second deals with old flags *that have been handled* by *reading the flag summary*, which is inapplicable to this case and so doubly irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

You can see what you wrote in a custom moderator flag in your flag history:

[image]

Comment: Please see comment on question. This sidesteps the problem but doesn't solve it.

Comment: Yes, you posted the comment just before I submitted my answer. I understand this solution doesn't work for you; it might still help other people with the same problem.