# Why can't I flag for moderator attention after flagging as "offensive"?

Tags: feature-request, flags, offensive

There was a [user](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/2671/user2671) on Lifehacks that just went about posting a litany of low-quality non-answers, the kind of stuff that should deserve the "offensive" flag.*

I flagged a couple of them as "offensive," but then realized that my flags might be better spent flagging one of the posts and describing the users entire behavior, hopefully catching the attention of SE staff (no mods on LH, yet).

I was a little confused when I was unable to flag an answer I had previously flagged as "offensive" because "You have already flagged this post for moderator attention."

[image: entering custom flag message]

[image: red flag error claiming that "You have already flagged this post for moderator attention."]

So I guess this is kinda a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request); please let us raise ([cast? throw?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19927390#19927390)) a custom flag even after an "offensive" flag has been raised, so that an abusive user like this one can be pointed out to moderators through flags, as has been recommended in several MSE posts.

---

* E.g., as an answer to [How to get out of the public restroom with clean hands?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/2232/59), that user [posted](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/4210/59)

> do not touch anything. it's so simple [censored]

Comment: And I see from your screen shots that [this problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184809/162102) remains unaddressed. :-(

Comment: On the upshot, for answers like that, even if there are many, you don't need to involve the mods at all. With a few posts removed as offensive, the system block the user from posting anything again. Problem solved.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks for the info; good to know.

Answer (score 8):

That error message is just vague in what it's trying to tell you. The system does not allow you to have two **active** flags on a single post. So you are not allowed to submit another flag until your offensive flag has been processed and either marked helpful or declined.

This restriction is in place to prevent users abusing flags to bump posts to the top of the moderator's flags queue, because more flags = higher placement. It also makes sure that their previous flag or message actually gets *seen* and processed before letting them tack on something else (and subsequently prevents the annoying "sorry you can ignore this" flags).

Comment: Once an 'offensive' flag is marked helpful, the post is deleted, so many users aren't going to be able to flag it again anyway. It would be better just to flag a separate post, with the custom explanation

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I do:

1. Flag all the offensive posts as such. That will help to get them deleted quickly. 6 offensive flags will kill the post.
2. Flag *another* post (It's helpful to mods if you can flag one of your own, or from the same thread), and describe the problem, and provide links for the mods to follow.

There is no reason why you should need two flags on one post, that I can see.